# QMutexLocker() causes UI to freeze

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, mutex, robotics

I have a controller class which controls a robot (attached over serial interface). This controller is attached to a view. In addition to that I have a thread derived from `QThread` which periodically reads out the status of the robot.

Reading out the status must not colide with robot commands which get tiggered from the userinterface. Therefore I locked every robot acces with a mutex using `QMutexLocker` but this causes my userinterface to freeze if such a mutex block gets executed.

```
class RobotControl(QObject):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super(RobotControl, self).__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.updatethread = UpdatePositionAndStatus(self.robot)
        self.mutex = QMutex()
        self.connect(self.updatethread, SIGNAL("updateStatus( QString ) "), self.print_error)
        self.updatethread.start()

@pyqtSlot()  
def init_robot(self):
    """
    Initializes the serial interface to the robot interface and checks if
    there is really a robot interface available.
    """
    with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
        # Open interface
        try:
            index = self.view.robotcontrolui.get_selected_interface_index()
            interface = self.interfaces.item(index).text()
            self.robot = RobotController(interface)
        except DeviceError:
            self.view.error_dlg(self.tr("Couldn't open interface {0}!".format(interface)))
            self.robot = None
            return

        # Check if there is really a robot interface on the selected serial
        # interface with trying to read status byte
        try:
            self.robot.status()
        except DeviceError:
            # In case of failure release interface
            self.close_robot()
            self.view.error_dlg(self.tr("Couldn't initialize robot interface!"))
            return

        self.view.robotcontrolui.bt_open_interface.setEnabled(False)
        self.view.robotcontrolui.bt_close_interface.setEnabled(True)

class UpdatePositionAndStatus(QThread):
    def __init__(self, robot, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.robot = robot
        self.mutex = QMutex()
    def run(self):
        """ 
        This function continously reads out the position and the status to for 
        updating it on the userinterface.
        """
        try:
            while True:
                if self.robot is not None:
                    # Do robot communication under a lock
                    self.mutex.lock()
                    (_, rel_pos) = self.robot.read_position()
                    status = self.robot.status()
                    self.mutex.unlock()

                    # Display position and status on userinterface
                    self.view.robotcontrolui.update_position_and_status(rel_pos, status)

                # Wait 1 seccond for next update
                QThread.sleep(1.0)
        except DeviceError:
            # Release lock on robot
            self.mutex.unlock()
            self.emit(SIGNAL("updateStatus( QString )"), self.tr("Error while updating current position and status!"))
```

After triggering the init method the userinterface freezes and the program crashes: Why is this so? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell because your code sample is incomplete, but I see two fundamental problems with this code:

1. You are locking two different QMutex objects. In order for mutual exclusion to work properly, both threads must be locking the *same* mutex object.
2. You appear to be directly interacting with the GUI from the update thread at this line:

   ```
   self.view.robotcontrolui.update_position_and_status(rel_pos, status)
   ```

   Performing GUI operations may *only* be done from the GUI thread in Qt. It's a fair bet that this is causing your crash. See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html

Comment: @1: Thanks for that hint. Now changed to one mutex, but doesn't solve the problem either. @2: `RobotControl` is held in the main `QApplication` so it's inside the GUI thread. Showing the error dialogs inside the exception works which invokes the gui too. I'm aware of this problem - that's the reason why the update thread doesn't invoke the gui directly rather than sending a slot. I'm trying to make an working minimum example tomorrow.

Comment: It doesn't matter that RobotControl was defined from within the main thread; the call to update_position_and_status comes from within UpdatePositionAndStatus.run, which is running in a separate thread. The only way this could be acceptable is if update_position_and_status does not directly interact with the GUI, but instead safely passes a message to the GUI thread telling it how to update.

Comment: Instead of calling that method directly, emit another signal that your main thread is connected to and will call the method. Good answer Luke.

Comment: Oh, I was misunderstandin you. It's right update_position_and_status() must be called within a signal. Nevertheless I reduces my issue by removing the aditional thread. Only the init_robot() has now the mutex. I set a breakboint and directly after the `with QMutexLocker()` statement the userinterface starts to freeze.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a deadlock from locking that mutex too many times. Since you took the thread out (which is good--they're probably unnecessary unless you expect to block a long time waiting for a serial response), there should no longer be any need for mutexes; just take them out.

Comment: Well. I reduced the problem further. In the above coode while init_robot(): There are two try-blocks: the first to open the device and the secon for checking if there is really a robot connected to the interface. If there is no robot connected to the cost I get internally a timeout after 1 second which throws a `DeviceError`. And that causes the problem: The robot is in office, I'm working at home, so I should get a timeout (this works without mutex), but with mutex it hangs and there comes no timeout. I'm using `PySerial` for the serial communication - maybe there is a bug?

Comment: Another weird behaviour: Using `threading.Lock()` works as expected.